# Forcing a context switch from the userland on Linux?

Tags: linux, scheduling

**Is it possible to advice the kernel to perform an immediate context switch to a different thread, bypassing the scheduler logic?**

For example, if I've just created a thread/process with `clone` and I want to begin its execution straight away, renouncing the current context immediately, instead of waiting for the next time the kernel reschedules stuff.

Ideally, I'm looking for something identical to the `thread_switch` call on the Mach kernel.

Comment: If you really, no kidding need the thread to run RIGHT NOW, then you should give it a real-time priority and let the kernel take care of it.  (But you probably don't... can you say why you want this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to control context switches, as the kernel probably knows much better than you when to do it.  Specially since a context switch is considered a costly operation (due to cache invalidation, mostly).

But, if you really need to force a scheduler cycle, you can use [the `sched_yield()` system call](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html).

Comment: `sched_yield` will only force the current thread off the CPU, nothing guarantees the next thread to run is the thread the OP wants to run.

Comment: @Job, although I agree with your statement, it is not unlikely to switch to that other thread if that's the process OP is developing is the main process running on that computer...

Comment: If you are using the pthread library, there is the `pthread_yield()` function too (which calls the `sched_yield()` on Linux.)

Comment: I think I have a legit reason to want this: while doing timing measurement it turns out that the chance for an anomaly (ie, 30% longer time to execute test snippet) is heavily correlated with measurements in the same tight loop. Forcing a context switch after every measurement should decouple these correlations. The statement "You shouldn't be trying to control switches" is therefore wrong (it is too strong, seemingly applying ALWAYS, the way it is stated). You could add the word 'probably' in there ("You probably shouldn't..."). Or add "Unless you know what you are doing, you shouldn't..."